# angularjs: chain promise to itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I want to run my promise again when it will resolve. Something like that

```
var myPromise = 
MyService
    .send("req")
    .then(function(res) {
        return myPromise;
    });
```

Here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10609/. Of course I won't do something as stupid as in example.

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to do then?

Comment: Your fiddle wasn't working, so here's a link that actually outputs something. http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10609/

Comment: Ok, thanks. Sorry for that. I will update my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understand, you want to loop the call:

```
function sendMyService() {
    MyService
        .send("req")
        .then(function(res) {
            sendMyService();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That code won't run anything. Assuming what comes back from that promise is a function body (as it's very unclear what you want to do), you can do something like this:

```
var myPromise;
MyService
    .send("req")
    .then(function(res) {
        myPromise = res();
    });
```